# Working with self.view after refactoring code

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, charts, drawing

I've been doing some testing with a cool charts framework (http://www.shinobicontrols.com/shinobicharts/) and so far I got them working on my project. They look great!

Just as I do on any tests, I implement the examples as simple as I can and then, when it's working, I move on to improve things a bit in the code-organization department.

After I felt comfortable with what I had I started refactoring the code a bit. Now I can't get the charts to draw on my view. I've tested the calls to methods with NSLog and everything is being called as expected. It is the view handling what got me spinning here. Let me explain what I had (when it was working) and what I did (to broke it).

Working scenario:

- ReportsViewController
  1) Imported chartLibrary.h
  2) Imported chartDatasource.h
  3) Created view and added with `[self.view addSubview:chart];`

All in the same place. All good.

What I did to organize my code:

1) Created a new class "ChartReports" (first I thought it should be NSObject but then I couldn't work with views so I changed to UIViewController)
2) Moved all imports and drawing code to this new class. Create drawing methods for each type of chart.
3) Imported "ChartReports" into "ReportsViewController"
4) Created new object (of ChartReports type) and called the new method to "drawChartX" in the exact same place as I had the whole code before (inside "ReportsViewController")

It all went south :(

The thing is that the call is correct, the method "drawChartX" is called and I NSLog from beginning to end to make sure the code is executing, but nothing is draw in the screen.

I create it and call it like this:

```
ChartReports *chart = [[ChartReports alloc] init];

[chart drawChartX];
```

When I see the code I moved (from "ReportsViewController" to "ChartReports") I notice it still says "self.view" everywhere. I thinks this is the place where the drawing is breaking. "self" originally referred to "ReportsViewController" and now it means "ChartReports".

So, after all of that: How can I tell "ChartReports" to draw on "ReportsViewController".view and not on its own view?

I tried variables and properties with no luck. Should I maybe send the name of the view as a method parameter?

I'm sorry to post such a long explanation but I'm out of ideas to try. Any general tip would be more than helpful to get back on the right path.

Thanks as usual,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ChartReports object should not draw on your ReportsViewController, this would break basic MVC principles.  Instead, you should organize your code so that the ChartReports object creates and returns a view (i.e. the chart) that your ReportsViewController will then add to its view using `addSubview`.

In this way you can still encapsulate the creation of the charts in a separate object (ChartReports) but you are leaving the work of displaying the chart to your view controller, which is its job.

Comment: Hi @jonkroll. I understand what you say.  I'll try to implement it (I'm new at this) but I have another question derived from your keen observation of the MVC.  Does "drawing" here refers only to the "addSubview" part or things like initWithFrame, autoresizingMask, and label assignment are also included? I'd say no, but if you can confirm I'll be leaving all of that on the ChartsReport object.

Comment: I'd say it's ok for ChartsReport to handle all aspects of creating and configuring the chart view, which includes all the things you mention: the init, autoresizingMask, assigning property values, etc.  That way your view controller won't need to know any of the details about setting up the view, and the ChartsReport object won't need to know anything about how the view is used once it is set up.